# Transactions from ArangoDB java driver fails to change anything in the database

Tags: java, arangodb

I am trying to send a transaction through the Java driver in my spring application.

The following is the simplified code.

```
@Test
public void rawTransactionTest(){
    var appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataLoaderApplication.class);
    var arangoOperations = appContext.getBean(ArangoOperations.class);
    String action = "function(){\n" +
            " db = require(\"@arangodb\").db; \n" +
            "db._query(\"LET doc = {title: \\\"Hello\\\"} "+
            "UPSERT { _key: doc._key } INSERT doc._key == null ? UNSET(doc, \\\"_key\\\") : doc " +
            "REPLACE doc IN Books OPTIONS { ignoreRevs: false } RETURN NEW\");\n" +
            "return \"Success\"; \n" +
            "}";
    System.out.println(action);
    var tOpts = new TransactionOptions();
    tOpts.writeCollections("Books");
    tOpts.waitForSync(true);
    var result = arangoOperations.driver().db().transaction(action, String.class, tOpts);
    System.out.println("Commit");

}
```

This returns the return value "Success" in the variable result. But the database remains unchanged. Doing the same thing in ArangoShell works perfectly fine. The ArangoShell code is as follows -

```
db._executeTransaction({
collections: { 
  write: ["Books"]
},
action: function(){
    db = require("@arangodb").db; 
    db._query("LET doc = {title: \"Hello\"} UPSERT { _key: doc._key } "+
        "INSERT doc._key == null ? UNSET(doc, \"_key\") : doc REPLACE doc"+
        " IN Books OPTIONS { ignoreRevs: false } RETURN NEW");
    return "Success";   
}
});
```

This code works fine from the shell. Other non-transaction queries work fine from he same Spring-container.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The .db() only points to the _system database. Had to pass the database name to fix it.